# Create page redirection based on input results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a webpage with a searchbar in it (based on an html input and the js file shown below which analyze the string being searched by the user and result in a product (if exists). I would like to create links for those results which redirect to a webpage (which for now can be a blank page, as it needs to be developed.

This is the js code developed so far:

````
const searches = [

 {name: 'Product 1'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 1" if clicked
 
 {name: 'Product 2'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 2" if clicked

 {name: 'Product 3'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 3" if clicked

 {name: 'Product 4'} // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 4" if clicked
];

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
const suggestionsPanel = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
 const input = searchInput.value;
 suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
 var suggestions = [];
 encontrados = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<searches.length && encontrados<4; i++){
     if(searches[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) != -1){
         suggestions.push(searches[i]);
         encontrados++;
     }
 }
 suggestions.forEach(function(suggested) {
   const div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = suggested.name;
   suggestionsPanel.appendChild(div);
 });
 if (input === '') {
   suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';  
 }
}) ```
````

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <a href="https://www.mixi.es" class="navbar-brand"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 99 99" enable-background="new 0 0 99 99" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#ACD7E4" d="M85.95,98.88H12.37c-6.78,0-12.28-5.5-12.28-12.28V13.02c0-6.78,5.5-12.28,12.28-12.28h73.58c6.78,0,12.28,5.5,12.28,12.28V86.6C98.23,93.38,92.73,98.88,85.95,98.88z"/><g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M7.96,66.3c-0.68,0-1.17-0.11-1.49-0.32s-0.53-0.5-0.64-0.85c-0.11-0.35-0.16-0.78-0.16-1.28v-21.1c0-0.46,0.05-0.86,0.16-1.2c0.11-0.34,0.33-0.59,0.67-0.77s0.84-0.27,1.52-0.27c0.78,0,1.34,0.15,1.68,0.45c0.34,0.3,0.51,0.83,0.51,1.57l-0.21,2.29c0.25-0.53,0.62-1.07,1.12-1.6c0.5-0.53,1.09-1.01,1.79-1.44c0.69-0.43,1.43-0.76,2.21-1.01c0.78-0.25,1.58-0.37,2.4-0.37c1.24,0,2.35,0.22,3.33,0.67c0.98,0.44,1.86,1.07,2.64,1.89c0.78,0.82,1.44,1.83,1.97,3.04c0.71-1.17,1.46-2.17,2.26-3.01c0.8-0.83,1.71-1.47,2.72-1.92c1.01-0.44,2.16-0.67,3.44-0.67c2.06,0,3.77,0.51,5.14,1.52c1.37,1.01,2.4,2.43,3.09,4.26c0.69,1.83,1.04,4.02,1.04,6.58v11.13c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.32,0.63-0.64,0.83s-0.83,0.29-1.54,0.29c-0.67,0-1.19-0.11-1.54-0.32c-0.36-0.21-0.58-0.5-0.67-0.85c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V52.72c0-1.56-0.2-2.93-0.59-4.1c-0.39-1.17-0.96-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.75-0.64-1.72-0.96-2.93-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.32-3.38,0.96c-0.98,0.64-1.73,1.54-2.26,2.69s-0.8,2.53-0.8,4.13v11.24c0,0.53-0.11,1-0.32,1.39c-0.21,0.39-0.53,0.67-0.96,0.83c-0.43,0.16-0.96,0.19-1.6,0.08c-0.53-0.04-0.94-0.17-1.23-0.4s-0.46-0.51-0.53-0.85c-0.07-0.34-0.11-0.72-0.11-1.15V52.72c0-1.56-0.19-2.93-0.56-4.1s-0.94-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.76-0.64-1.75-0.96-2.96-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.33-3.38,0.99c-0.98,0.66-1.73,1.57-2.26,2.74c-0.53,1.17-0.8,2.52-0.8,4.05v11.19c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.63-0.67,0.83C9.2,66.2,8.67,66.3,7.96,66.3z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M52.23,34.12c-0.78,0-1.37-0.12-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.46c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.2,1-0.29,1.78-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.71,0.32s0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96c0.12,0.43,0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C53.6,34.02,53.01,34.12,52.23,34.12z M52.23,66.3c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V42.86c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25s0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83c0.34-0.18,0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85c0.11,0.37,0.16,0.81,0.16,1.3v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C53.42,66.21,52.91,66.3,52.23,66.3z"/></g></g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M65.03,57.61l-4.59,5c-0.52,0.57-0.88,1.05-1.08,1.43c-0.2,0.39-0.2,0.75,0,1.09c0.2,0.34,0.56,0.7,1.08,1.09c0.52,0.35,0.97,0.59,1.35,0.72c0.38,0.12,0.77,0.08,1.17-0.13c0.4-0.21,0.86-0.58,1.38-1.12l7.42-8.08H65.03z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M84.36,64.04c-0.18-0.39-0.55-0.87-1.11-1.43l-8.04-8.76l8.1-8.83c0.56-0.57,0.92-1.05,1.08-1.43c0.16-0.39,0.14-0.75-0.06-1.09c-0.2-0.34-0.58-0.72-1.14-1.14c-0.76-0.57-1.38-0.81-1.86-0.72c-0.48,0.09-1.12,0.52-1.92,1.3l-7.56,8.24l-7.56-8.24c-0.48-0.53-0.9-0.9-1.26-1.12c-0.36-0.21-0.73-0.27-1.11-0.16c-0.38,0.11-0.83,0.34-1.35,0.69c-0.6,0.39-1,0.75-1.2,1.09c-0.2,0.34-0.21,0.71-0.03,1.12c0.18,0.41,0.53,0.89,1.05,1.46l8.1,8.83l-0.01,0.01l3.37,3.67l0.01-0.01l7.5,8.18c0.56,0.53,1.04,0.9,1.44,1.12c0.4,0.21,0.79,0.26,1.17,0.13c0.38-0.12,0.81-0.36,1.29-0.72c0.56-0.39,0.93-0.75,1.11-1.09C84.54,64.79,84.54,64.43,84.36,64.04z"/></g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M90.03,34.55c-0.78,0-1.37-0.11-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.47c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.19,1-0.29,1.79-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.7,0.32c0.39,0.21,0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96s0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C91.4,34.44,90.81,34.55,90.03,34.55z M90.03,66.72c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V43.28c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25c0.11-0.37,0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83s0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85s0.16,0.81,0.16,1.31v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C91.21,66.63,90.71,66.72,90.03,66.72z"/></g></g></g></svg></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed d-flex d-lg-none flex-column justify-content-around" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

      <span class="toggler-icon top-bar"></span>

      <span class="toggler-icon middle-bar"></span>

      <span class="toggler-icon bottom-bar"></span>

    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">

        <li class="nav-item navbar-modal nav-item-mobile"><a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search search" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#dad7d7" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" /><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" /></svg>&nbsp;Buscar en mixi.es</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tienda">Tienda</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="calculadora">Calculadora</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contacto">Contacto</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item navbar-modal nav-item-desktop"><a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search search" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#dad7d7" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" /><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" /></svg></a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="#">

          <div class="searchBox-fakeInput">
            
            <div class="searchBox-inputWrapper">
              <input type="text" class="search-input form-control searchBox-input js-searchBox-input" placeholder="Productos, colaboradores, sobre MIXI...">
            </div>
            
            <div class="searchBox-clearWrapper">
              <span class="searchBox-clear js-clearSearchBox"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="suggestions"></div>

        </form>                           

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Might make some sense if you provide some HTML you re basing this off.

Comment: @Melooo7, I just modified the statement with the HTML affected by this searchbar. It´s included in the navbar as a bootstrap modal which displays when clicked (and depends if it is on mobile or desktop to display as nav-item-desktop or nav-item-mobile.
As you can see, all strings which are compared come from the js file, so I guess the links have to go somewhere in that file and not in the HTML.

Comment: So put the target URLs, or whatever data you need to dynamically create them, into the objects inside `searches`. And then inside your `suggestions.forEach()` loop, create an `a` element, set its href & innerHTML, and then append it to the div.

Comment: @CBroe I´m new in js, should this be created directly inside the js file?

Comment: Yes, of course, you implement it within the already existing code you have shown us.

Comment: So I tried the code from @Melooo7 and indeed creates a link in the result, but the link points to an unknown link (which is configured to a custom error 404 I created). How can I link the correct page once it is created? For example, lets say is www.mixi.es/product1

Comment: You have to change the part in the code where I put thee google link for now. Just replace google.com with mixi.es. If my answer was useful please upvote it or mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please note that I used jQuery so you need to load the script in case its not already implemented.

```js
const searches = [

 {name: 'Product 1'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 1" if clicked
 
 {name: 'Product 2'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 2" if clicked

 {name: 'Product 3'}, // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 3" if clicked

 {name: 'Product 4'} // Should redirect to a webpage related with "Product 4" if clicked
];

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
const suggestionsPanel = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
 const input = searchInput.value;
 suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
 var suggestions = [];
 encontrados = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<searches.length && encontrados<4; i++){
     if(searches[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) != -1){
         suggestions.push(searches[i]);
         encontrados++;
     }
 }
 suggestions.forEach(function(suggested) {
   const div = document.createElement('div');
   //div.innerHTML = suggested.name;
   $(div).append('<a href="www.google.com/'+suggested.name.replace(' ','')+'">'+suggested.name+'</a>');
   suggestionsPanel.appendChild(div);
 });
 if (input === '') {
   suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';  
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <a href="https://www.mixi.es" class="navbar-brand"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 99 99" enable-background="new 0 0 99 99" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#ACD7E4" d="M85.95,98.88H12.37c-6.78,0-12.28-5.5-12.28-12.28V13.02c0-6.78,5.5-12.28,12.28-12.28h73.58c6.78,0,12.28,5.5,12.28,12.28V86.6C98.23,93.38,92.73,98.88,85.95,98.88z"/><g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M7.96,66.3c-0.68,0-1.17-0.11-1.49-0.32s-0.53-0.5-0.64-0.85c-0.11-0.35-0.16-0.78-0.16-1.28v-21.1c0-0.46,0.05-0.86,0.16-1.2c0.11-0.34,0.33-0.59,0.67-0.77s0.84-0.27,1.52-0.27c0.78,0,1.34,0.15,1.68,0.45c0.34,0.3,0.51,0.83,0.51,1.57l-0.21,2.29c0.25-0.53,0.62-1.07,1.12-1.6c0.5-0.53,1.09-1.01,1.79-1.44c0.69-0.43,1.43-0.76,2.21-1.01c0.78-0.25,1.58-0.37,2.4-0.37c1.24,0,2.35,0.22,3.33,0.67c0.98,0.44,1.86,1.07,2.64,1.89c0.78,0.82,1.44,1.83,1.97,3.04c0.71-1.17,1.46-2.17,2.26-3.01c0.8-0.83,1.71-1.47,2.72-1.92c1.01-0.44,2.16-0.67,3.44-0.67c2.06,0,3.77,0.51,5.14,1.52c1.37,1.01,2.4,2.43,3.09,4.26c0.69,1.83,1.04,4.02,1.04,6.58v11.13c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.32,0.63-0.64,0.83s-0.83,0.29-1.54,0.29c-0.67,0-1.19-0.11-1.54-0.32c-0.36-0.21-0.58-0.5-0.67-0.85c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V52.72c0-1.56-0.2-2.93-0.59-4.1c-0.39-1.17-0.96-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.75-0.64-1.72-0.96-2.93-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.32-3.38,0.96c-0.98,0.64-1.73,1.54-2.26,2.69s-0.8,2.53-0.8,4.13v11.24c0,0.53-0.11,1-0.32,1.39c-0.21,0.39-0.53,0.67-0.96,0.83c-0.43,0.16-0.96,0.19-1.6,0.08c-0.53-0.04-0.94-0.17-1.23-0.4s-0.46-0.51-0.53-0.85c-0.07-0.34-0.11-0.72-0.11-1.15V52.72c0-1.56-0.19-2.93-0.56-4.1s-0.94-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.76-0.64-1.75-0.96-2.96-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.33-3.38,0.99c-0.98,0.66-1.73,1.57-2.26,2.74c-0.53,1.17-0.8,2.52-0.8,4.05v11.19c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.63-0.67,0.83C9.2,66.2,8.67,66.3,7.96,66.3z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M52.23,34.12c-0.78,0-1.37-0.12-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.46c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.2,1-0.29,1.78-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.71,0.32s0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96c0.12,0.43,0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C53.6,34.02,53.01,34.12,52.23,34.12z M52.23,66.3c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V42.86c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25s0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83c0.34-0.18,0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85c0.11,0.37,0.16,0.81,0.16,1.3v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C53.42,66.21,52.91,66.3,52.23,66.3z"/></g></g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M65.03,57.61l-4.59,5c-0.52,0.57-0.88,1.05-1.08,1.43c-0.2,0.39-0.2,0.75,0,1.09c0.2,0.34,0.56,0.7,1.08,1.09c0.52,0.35,0.97,0.59,1.35,0.72c0.38,0.12,0.77,0.08,1.17-0.13c0.4-0.21,0.86-0.58,1.38-1.12l7.42-8.08H65.03z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M84.36,64.04c-0.18-0.39-0.55-0.87-1.11-1.43l-8.04-8.76l8.1-8.83c0.56-0.57,0.92-1.05,1.08-1.43c0.16-0.39,0.14-0.75-0.06-1.09c-0.2-0.34-0.58-0.72-1.14-1.14c-0.76-0.57-1.38-0.81-1.86-0.72c-0.48,0.09-1.12,0.52-1.92,1.3l-7.56,8.24l-7.56-8.24c-0.48-0.53-0.9-0.9-1.26-1.12c-0.36-0.21-0.73-0.27-1.11-0.16c-0.38,0.11-0.83,0.34-1.35,0.69c-0.6,0.39-1,0.75-1.2,1.09c-0.2,0.34-0.21,0.71-0.03,1.12c0.18,0.41,0.53,0.89,1.05,1.46l8.1,8.83l-0.01,0.01l3.37,3.67l0.01-0.01l7.5,8.18c0.56,0.53,1.04,0.9,1.44,1.12c0.4,0.21,0.79,0.26,1.17,0.13c0.38-0.12,0.81-0.36,1.29-0.72c0.56-0.39,0.93-0.75,1.11-1.09C84.54,64.79,84.54,64.43,84.36,64.04z"/></g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M90.03,34.55c-0.78,0-1.37-0.11-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.47c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.19,1-0.29,1.79-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.7,0.32c0.39,0.21,0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96s0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C91.4,34.44,90.81,34.55,90.03,34.55z M90.03,66.72c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V43.28c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25c0.11-0.37,0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83s0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85s0.16,0.81,0.16,1.31v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C91.21,66.63,90.71,66.72,90.03,66.72z"/></g></g></g></svg></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed d-flex d-lg-none flex-column justify-content-around" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

      <span class="toggler-icon top-bar"></span>

      <span class="toggler-icon middle-bar"></span>

      <span class="toggler-icon bottom-bar"></span>

    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">

        <li class="nav-item navbar-modal nav-item-mobile"><a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search search" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#dad7d7" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" /><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" /></svg>&nbsp;Buscar en mixi.es</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tienda">Tienda</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="calculadora">Calculadora</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contacto">Contacto</a></li>

        <li class="nav-item navbar-modal nav-item-desktop"><a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search search" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#dad7d7" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" /><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" /></svg></a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="#">

          <div class="searchBox-fakeInput">
            
            <div class="searchBox-inputWrapper">
              <input type="text" class="search-input form-control searchBox-input js-searchBox-input" placeholder="Productos, colaboradores, sobre MIXI...">
            </div>
            
            <div class="searchBox-clearWrapper">
              <span class="searchBox-clear js-clearSearchBox"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="suggestions"></div>

        </form>                           

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```